# how to pass values from sale to invoice odoo?

Tags: odoo

I have created new one2many field like order lines in sale after other info tab. Also,I have created a new one2many field like invoice lines in invoice form after other info tab.

What i need to do is, I have to pass values from sale one2many field to invoice one2many field while clicking create invoice button.

I have tried inheriting _prepare_invoice and _prepare_invoice_line function in default. It does not work for other one2many field.

Could anyone please help me to do this!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **`Odoo14/Odoo13/Odoo12/Odoo11`** then you need to override the `sale.order` method i.e **`_prepare_invoice`**.
Below is the example of Odoo14

```
@api.model
def _prepare_invoice(self):
    """
    Prepare the dict of values to create the new invoice for a sales order. This method may be
    overridden to implement custom invoice generation (making sure to call super() to establish
    a clean extension chain).
    """
    self.ensure_one()
    journal = self.env['account.move'].with_context(default_move_type='out_invoice')._get_default_journal()
    if not journal:
        raise UserError(_('Please define an accounting sales journal for the company %s (%s).') % (self.company_id.name, self.company_id.id))

    invoice_vals = {
        'ref': self.client_order_ref or '',
        'move_type': 'out_invoice',
        'narration': self.note,
        'currency_id': self.pricelist_id.currency_id.id,
        'campaign_id': self.campaign_id.id,
        'medium_id': self.medium_id.id,
        'source_id': self.source_id.id,
        'invoice_user_id': self.user_id and self.user_id.id,
        'team_id': self.team_id.id,
        'partner_id': self.partner_invoice_id.id,
        'partner_shipping_id': self.partner_shipping_id.id,
        'fiscal_position_id': (self.fiscal_position_id or self.fiscal_position_id.get_fiscal_position(self.partner_invoice_id.id)).id,
        'partner_bank_id': self.company_id.partner_id.bank_ids[:1].id,
        'journal_id': journal.id,  # company comes from the journal
        'invoice_origin': self.name,
        'invoice_payment_term_id': self.payment_term_id.id,
        'payment_reference': self.reference,
        'transaction_ids': [(6, 0, self.transaction_ids.ids)],
        'invoice_line_ids': [],
        'company_id': self.company_id.id,
        'tax_line': [(6, 0, self.tax_line.ids)] //This is my customize field.
        }
    return invoice_vals
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not pass values!

Comment: Can you please explain your problem after overriding this method because I'm currently using same method for passing values from SO to invoice

Comment: In account.move, I.m having this o2m field
account_tax_line_ids = fields.One2many('account.tax.line', 'account_line_id', string='Taxes')

Comment: In sale order, sale_tax_line_ids = fields.One2many('sale.order.tax', 'sale_id', string='Tax Lines', readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, copy=True)

Comment: 'account_tax_line_ids': [(6, 0, self.sale_tax_line_ids.ids)] I put this in prepare_invoice #my customize field

Comment: It did not show any error and also it did not pass value while click on create invoice button in sale.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly pass the o2M which will be entirely different ids.
'account_tax_line_ids': [(6, 0, self.sale_tax_line_ids.ids)] is not possible.

> If you need to edit account_tax_line_ids again in the invoice form and
> sale_tax_line_ids value should not change, then try below.

```
@api.multi
def _prepare_invoice(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    invoice_vals = super(SaleOrder, self)._prepare_invoice()
    invoice_vals['account_tax_line_ids'] = [(0, 0, {'FIELD1': line.FIELD1_VALUE, ... } for line in self.sale_tax_line_ids]
    return invoice_vals

Specify the fields in side Dictionary.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did it by copying o2m from sale to o2m in invoice. I've done it using list.

Answer (score 0):

Read your comments and find out why it's not shown or not getting errors.

In the sale order field:

```
sale_tax_line_ids = fields.One2many('**sale.order.tax**', 'sale_id', string='Tax Lines', readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]}, copy=True)
```

And, in the account, move:

```
account_tax_line_ids = fields.One2many('**account.tax.line**', 'account_line_id', string='Taxes') and you set value like 'account_tax_line_ids': [(6, 0,**self.sale_tax_line_ids.ids**)]
```

So in the `account_tax_line_ids` fields, you should set the `account.tax.line` model records, but you are trying to set `sale.order.tax` model records.

Also, you can see in the odoo default, like in the sale order line, there is `product_id`, so it is related to the `product.product` model, and same with account: move line there `product_id`, which relates to `product.product` model. So it sets sale order line product to account move line product.